# Using String stored on variable as dash media source

Tags: android, mpeg-dash, exoplayer, mpd

I have a content of dash mpd file on string variable

```
String MPDString = "<?xml version="1.0"?>
" +
            "<!-- MPD file Generated with GPAC version 0.5.2-DEV-revVersion: 0.5.2-426-gc5ad4e4+dfsg5-1build1  at 2018-03-07T11:10:44.851Z-->\n" +
            ...........
            </MPD>
            ";
```

I want to use this string as dashsource but confused
I looked the link : [Create MPD file from String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48626074/create-mpd-file-from-string?answertab=active#tab-top)
But still confused
Can anyone please provide me some more information

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the answer you linked to in your question you will see the last example is creating the manifest from a string named 'manifestString'.

```js
DataSource.Factory manifestDataSourceFactory = new DataSource.Factory() {
    @Override
    public DataSource createDataSource() {
        return new ByteArrayDataSource(manifestString.getBytes());
    }
};
```

Assunming your 'MPDString' in your example is a correctly formatted mod then you simply use it above in place of 'manifestString':

```js
DataSource.Factory manifestDataSourceFactory = new DataSource.Factory() {
    @Override
    public DataSource createDataSource() {
        return new ByteArrayDataSource(MPDString.getBytes());
    }
};
```

Comment: I have done as per the example, but while preparing exoplayer, i need a dashmediasource, and to create the dashmediasource, i need manifest uri as it is notnullable, exoPlayer.prepare(dashMediaSourceFactory.createMediaSource(????));